# Most Efficient / Easiest Way to Capture Multiple Entries in Same Field

Tags: oracle

I have been tasked with replicating a database that has been for some time used along with Cold Fusion and cleaning it up for use with a more modern web portal.

In an effort to fork out various lookup tables, I've ran into a particular column whose field may have up to eight different e-mail addresses for personnel (delimited by semicolons).

The reason for the multiple e-mail addresses is those individuals map to the same case / issue #.

What is the best way for me to parse through the current table and "tokenize" each e-mail address in order to copy it and other fields over to a new lookup table whereby each e-mail address gets its own row in the new lookup table?

In the meantime, the "legacy" database used with Cold Fusion will be in use until I've migrated things over satisfactorily.

Also, I'm a total newb to SQL so any links to similar problems to enhance your answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have a function to do this in SQL Server but I don't know if it'll work in Oracle.  Basically, in SQL Server, you'd have to parse the table row by row and run a table valued function to convert a delimited value into a table and store that separately (or you can use a CTE or whatever you see fit).  Other than that, I don't know of a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this, for example a short and easy version:

```
drop table bad_design purge;
create table bad_design (c1 varchar2(200 char));
insert into bad_design values ('a@a.com; b@b.com; c@c.com; d@d.com; e@e.com; f@f.com; g@g.com');
insert into bad_design values ('z@z.com; y@y.com; x@x.com; w@w.com; v@v.com; u@u.com; t@t.com');
insert into bad_design values ('o@o.com');
commit;
```

Then:

```
select
  trim(column_value) c1
from
  bad_design,
  xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(c1, ';', '","') || '"'))
;

a@a.com
b@b.com
c@c.com
d@d.com
e@e.com
f@f.com
g@g.com
z@z.com
y@y.com
x@x.com
w@w.com
v@v.com
u@u.com
t@t.com
o@o.com
```

Which you can simply insert into a new table if needed. Other methods:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle

Comment: Thanks for the example!  I was thrown off with the "column_value" argument because I'm still new to SQL.  I got desperate when I didn't know what the heck it was so I put it in where you did and low and behold it was a known parameter!